# Basic Auth for subdomain without https or shall I buy a second ssl certificate for subdomain?

Tags: ssl-certificate, subdomain, basic-authentication

I have small website project on a managed hosting server where https is used.

Now I would like to know if it is still secure to use a http subdomain (without  https) in combination with a basic auth restriction defined in .htaccess. I have only one security certificate that is used for the main website. Shell I buy a second security certificate for the subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use basic authentication with http you are basically sending your username and password unencrypted over the wire. So to answer the question: No your current approach is not secure. You should buy a ssl certificate or look into Lets encrypt if you dont want to buy another certificate again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Let's encrypt is new to me and sounds very interesting to me. But my hosting provider does not allow to import a certificate.

Comment: I guess then you have to stick with buying one :)